To trigger a sharepoint using webhook
The sharepoint webhook is not getting triggered. When I am trying to run it locally, I am receiving the below error:
Failed to create webhook subscription: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
    at settle (C:\Users\hadim\SharePointWebhook\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2019:12)
    at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\hadim\SharePointWebhook\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:3135:11)
    at Unzip.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at Axios.request (C:\Users\hadim\SharePointWebhook\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:4267:41)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async createWebhookSubscription (C:\Users\hadim\SharePointWebhook\server.js:47:26) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',

What is the issue here? Is it the code or issue with notification URL I am providing which I got from Azure? I checked many forums but I did not get any resolution. On running the code locally, I got  I am getting status: 400 error and the above attached errors.
    const express = require('express'); 
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const axios = require('axios');
    const { ConfidentialClientApplication } = require('@azure/msal-node');

    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

    const msalConfig = {
            auth: {
            clientId: '3ed3bac0-c01d-48ea-8aec-8382bfe09717',
            authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/37cf0ce8-ac09-4e7d-9ff2-f1da44914b3e',
            clientSecret: '-WK8Q~K3sxp_ucr~P-TE0roYY7LbHEnu6NqE5bmY',
            }
        };

    const cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

    async function getAccessToken() {
        const tokenRequest = {
            scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'],
        };

        try {
            const authResponse = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest);
            return authResponse.accessToken;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to acquire access token:', error);
            throw error;
        }
     }

    async function createWebhookSubscription() {
        const accessToken = await getAccessToken();

        const subscriptionRequest = {
            changeType: 'created',
            notificationUrl: 'https://bhnwebhooknodejspoc.azurewebsites.net',
            resource: '/sites/spomigration/lists/d1d1a68f-4186-498a-942b-bf4b113c4764',
            expirationDateTime: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600000).toISOString(),
            clientState: 'secretClientValue',
        };

        try {
            const response = await                  axios.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions', subscriptionRequest, {
                headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });

        console.log('Webhook created:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to create webhook subscription:', error);
    }
}

app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Webhook endpoint is up and running!');
});

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Webhook triggered:', req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
    createWebhookSubscription();
});

